# Creating getter for getting error messages from form in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, get

I am trying to make some getter that will return something like this

```
  get anyInvalid(): any {
    return this.formGroup.controls.endTime.errors || this.formGroup.errors?.invalidFixed || this.formGroup.errors?.endTimeIsRequired || this.formGroup.errors?.endTimeIsInvalid;
  }
```

But I got error

**error TS1109: Expression expected.**

Does anybody got idea where I got wrong, maybe some minor syntax?

Comment: The `?` that you're placing doesn't work in TypeScript. You'd have to use either `??` which was introduced as a part of the ESNext Standards or maybe check if what you're trying to access is actually defined.

Comment: ?? does not works also

Comment: @MiomirDancevic nullish coalescing `??` will work at typescript version 3.7 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Answer (score 3):

simply if any of the form controls is invalid the form it self is invalid so try like this

```
  get anyInvalid(): any {
    return this.properties.formGroup.invalid;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
get anyInvalid(): any {
  const fg = this.properties.formGroup;
  const { errors } = fg;
  let invalidFixed, endTimeIsRequired, endTimeIsInvalid;
  if (errors) {
    invalidFixed = errors.invalidFixed;
    endTimeIsRequired = errors.endTimeIsRequired;
    endTimeIsInvalid = errors.endTimeIsInvalid;
  }
  return fg.controls.endTime.errors || 
    invalidFixed || 
    endTimeIsRequired || 
    endTimeIsInvalid;
}
```